# Symfony Workflow Component and Security Voters?

Tags: php, symfony, workflow, symfony-security, symfony-workflows

**TL;DR: how can you add custom constraints (i.e. security voters) to transitions?**

My application needs some workflow management system, so I'd like to try Symfony's new [Workflow Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/workflow.html). Let's take a [Pull Request](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/state-machines.html) workflow as an example.

In this example, only states and their transitions are describes. But what if I want to add other constraints to this workflow? I can image some constraints:

- Only admins can accept Pull Request
- Users can only reopen their own Pull Request
- Users can not reopen PR's older than 1 year

While you can use [Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/usage.html#using-events) in this case, I don't think that's the best way to handle it, because an event is fired after `$workflow->apply()`. I want to know beforehand if a user is allowed to change the state, so I can hide or disable the button. (not [like this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/usage.html#usage-in-twig)).

The [LexikWorkflowBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikWorkflowBundle) solved this problem partially, by adding roles to the steps (transitions). Switching to this bundle might be a good idea, but I'd like to figure out how I can solve this problem without.

What is the best way to add custom entity constraints ('*PR older than 1 year can't be reopened*') and security constraints ('*only admins can accept PR's*', maybe by using Symfony's Security Voters) to transitions?

**Update:**
To clarify: I want to add permission control to my workflow, but that doesn't necessarily mean I want to tightly couple it to the Workflow Component. I'd like to stick to good practices, so the given solution should respect the single responsibility principle.

Comment: Yagni. Workflow component should be responsible for workflow only. Think about it other way round - transition is **one** of the constraint you are using in your application. Apply other constrains before or after `$workflow->can` is resolved, same way as you would use it in combination with ACL, for example.

Comment: I understand the other constraints should not be tightly coupled with the Workflow Component. But on the other hand, I want to have a single place where I validate all constraints (workflow, entity, security) for each transition to prevent spaghetti code in my controllers.

Comment: What stops you to create such place as a service which uses workflow as one of the constraints?

Comment: Technically, nothing. But I suppose I'm not the only one with this question, so there must be someone who figured out the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Even if you don't take single responsibility principle as the best solution, it is a good one. After all [Bolivar](http://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-bolivar-cannot-carry-double-o-henry-108-6-0696.jpg) does its best with a lone rider. Let the workflow do the transition logic, write your own constrains specific to your business logic, and compose them in a single service if you like. I wouldn't even mess with workflow Events.

Comment: I too am a bit skeptical about mixing workflow and permissions but if you really want to check permissions from inside of a workflow object then inject  security.authorization_checker which will give you access to the voters via the isGranted method.

Comment: @Cerad I'm not sure 'mixing' is the right word. I don't want to mix them, I just want to use them both. I want to check if a certain transition is valid (workflow) and if that user is allowed to create that transition (security).
I'm looking for a way that meets best practices.

Comment: Another approach might be to pass the workflow to the voter?  Just a thought.  Probably does not make sense.  Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: I've thought of that as well, but that won't work. In case of a workflow, I don't want to validate the entity but the transition.

Comment: If I do not misunderstand your use case, an event is exactly what you want to use here. Inside your event listener, you check some preconditions (which could also be a call to a voter) and then mark it as blocked (take a look again at the example you linked to to see how this can be done).

Comment: I'm now trying to implement it by using GuardEvent. I'll let you know how that works out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I found was implementing the **AuthorizationChecker** in the Workflow's **GuardListener**.

The [demo application](https://github.com/lyrixx/SFLive-Paris2016-Workflow/blob/7b92467a0d15c5e48cf898bd752a29040895fbaa/src/AppBundle/Workflow/GuardListener.php) gives a good example:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Workflow\Event\GuardEvent;

class GuardListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $checker)
    {
        $this->checker = $checker;
    }
    public function onTransition(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        // For all action, user should be logger
        if (!$this->checker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            $event->setBlocked(true);
        }
    }
    public function onTransitionJournalist(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$this->checker->isGranted('ROLE_JOURNALIST')) {
            $event->setBlocked(true);
        }
    }
    public function onTransitionSpellChecker(GuardEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$this->checker->isGranted('ROLE_SPELLCHECKER')) {
            $event->setBlocked(true);
        }
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'workflow.article.guard' => 'onTransition',
            'workflow.article.guard.journalist_approval' => 'onTransitionJournalist',
            'workflow.article.guard.spellchecker_approval' => 'onTransitionSpellChecker',
        ];
    }
```