# ERROR @ionic/app-scripts is required for ionic serve to work properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have cloned the my old project and run `npm install` and after that i run `ionic serve`

And i found this error

```
[ERROR] @ionic/app-scripts is required for ionic serve to work properly.

Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

This package is required for ionic serve in ionic/angular 4 projects.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I've used google for some research and directly found some approaches

Comment: What about the solution given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41566420/symfony-workflow-component-and-security-voters?

Comment: why you haven´t selected an answer?.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image]

To solve the above issue following below commands :

- npm install --rebuild
- npm install  node-sass --rebuild
- npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save

Comment: Hi @Garry  - as per the my understanding, some of the version does not match with the current app-script files, thus first we rebuild the npm, then after we rebuild the node-sass because of it install or modify the current package.json files and in last step we install latest app-script file

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry  but solution is more important then focus on other things

Comment: should be --save-dev for `app-scripts` to not be included in the production bundle

Answer (score 12):

Your question's title itself has the answer.

Try to install the following

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this after updating to Ionic 4. I ended up having to downgrade.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3399

Answer (score 3):

> delete your node_modules folder

Run:

```
npm install
```

wait until it finishes. Now you could run your project with:

```
ionic serve -l
```

Answer (score 2):

Exit the command panel and reopen again. then its works.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
npm update
```

that will make everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to deleting node_modules and running `npm install` as mentioned by @tnfaid, I also deleted `package-lock.json` file just to be sure. Also ran `npm audit fix`, to resolve any vulnerabilities. This worked for me.

Comment: Why then didn't you upvote @tnfaid's answer? Could go a long way in helping someone

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I upgraded from Ionic 3 to 4.  The problem is that `package.json` and `ionic.config.json` both changed from 3 to 4.  So when you do your copy-paste actions you have to be careful.

#### Ionic.config.json type should be `angular` (used to be "type": "ionic-angular")

```
{
  "name": "myProjectName",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular"
}
```

#### package.json scripts now follow angular style

You may have had something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint --bailOnLintError true",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "ionic:watch:before": "node ./bin/pre-build.js",
    "ionic:build:before": "node ./bin/pre-build.js"
},
```

That should now changed to standard angular in Ionic 4:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  }
```

delete '`"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"`',
save it and execute `ionic serve`.
It should work now.
After that, you can add `"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"` back.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing by running the following command:

```
npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out that it was a permission problem.

In my case I solved it in a different way. I had to change permission and then update

```
sudo chown -R thiagodias:thiagodias /Documents/ionic_workspace
:~/Documents/ionic_workspace/test$ sudo npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```